# Updating object values in jQuery by "finding" properties in a table

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a table which sums the values from another table while sorting them by category (first td corresponds to the value and third td corresponds to the sorting element).

The code below is an example of the current code (https://jsfiddle.net/p476bqxf/16/)

```
var entries = [0,0];

$('#secondTable tr').each(function(){
  switch ($(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").html()){
    case "One":
      entries[0] += parseInt($(this).find("td:first-child").html());
      break;
    case "Two":
      entries[1] += parseInt($(this).find("td:first-child").html());
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
});

$("#firstTable td").each(function(e){
  $(this).html(entries[e]);
});
```

However, to avoid repetitive code (since there are more than two sorting elements), I would like to use an Object instead of an Array but I get stuck with the syntax. Any suggestions on how to write this code properly would be greatly appreciated:

```
var entries = {
    "One" : 0,
    "Two": 0
};

$('#secondTable tr').each(function(){
    var n = $(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").html();
    entries.n += parseInt($(this).find("td:first-child").html());
    //entries.n doesn't work, the idea is to match the value of
    //every 3rd td with a property of the object...
});

$("#firstTable td").each(function(e){
    $(this).html(entries[e]);
    //entries[e] also doesn't work, since it's not an array
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `[]` object notation to access a property with a variable name

Then objects don't have guaranteed order so you would need an array of property names to specifiy the order

You can do something like:

```js
var entries = {
  "One": 0,
  "Two": 0
};

$('#secondTable tr').each(function() {
  var n = $(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").html();
  entries[n] += parseInt($(this).find("td:first-child").html());
});

["One", "Two"].forEach(function(v, i) {
  $("#firstTable td").eq(i).text(entries[v])
})
```

```css
#firstTable {
  background: green;
}

#secondTable {
  background: grey;
}

table {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="firstTable">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="secondTable">
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>Sthg</td>
    <td>One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>Sthg</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Sthg</td>
    <td>One</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, that shortened my code substantially! Would there also be a way to avoid typing all the "sorting" properties in your forEach function? Not that it matters in my case, simply out of curiosity.

Comment: If order doesn't matter You could do: `Object.keys(entries).forEach(function(v, i) {
  $("#firstTable td").eq(i).text(entries[v])
})`